# Symfony2 form with big collection

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm building a form involving a collection of different object. Basically, I give a date of beginning and a date of end, then javascript generates many time the data prototype and hence, I can have a huge amount of line generated.

I understand that I cannot expect to handle thousands of line but here my program displays an error: memory exhausted when I generate about 40 lines. To be more precise, symfony2 displays a white screen and when I go into the dev.log, I get:

> [2014-03-12 14:45:59] emergency.EMERGENCY: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16 bytes) {"type":1,"file":"Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DataCollector/Util/ValueExporter.php","line":29} []

This error is triggered when the program reach the line form->createView() whith the 40 entities () after they have been added in my data base.

If I increase the number of entities, symfony2 won't even store them in database. Is there a way, using symfony form logic to avoid those errors or should I look at some other ways of generating the form and the view of this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your memory limit is set to 32 MiB, that's very modest limit. Considering the fact, that Symfony itself uses about ~25 MiB of memory in dev environment there's not very much you could do about it.

Icrease your memory limit to some adequate level, 128 - 256 MiB should be fine. To do that, modify `memory_limit` directive in `php.ini` file:

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

Comment: Thanks. It definetly helps. But I think that I'll have to change a bit the way the code work because I'm getting some strange errors (like the profiler not working very well when this big collection is involved). May be it's not good practice to form->bind() or form->createView on massive collection. Or is it?

Comment: 1. Define "big collection". Is it a collection of 100, 1000 or 10000 elements? 2. You should stay with "default" form-handling architecture  provided by Symfony.

Comment: It can be quite big. The principle is that you give a beginning date and an end date to my javascript. It then generate a data-prototype row for every date between those 2 dates. Reasonably, I think this object could have to handle around 100 row. Then each row contains at least 2 objects (often a bit more, I would say maximum 10 objects per row). On the back end side, I persist a parent object that store the beginning date, the end date and the periodicity. I also store each row of this parent.